# Multiple filled.contour plots in one graph using with par(mfrow=c())

Tags: r, layout, graph, plot, contour

I am trying to construct a graph consisting of 2-3 `filled.contour` plots next to each other. The color scale is the same for all plots, and I would like only one z value key plot. I am having difficulties to do this with `par(mfrow=c(1,3))`

Example code:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
z <- matrix(outer(x,y,"+"),nrow=5)
filled.contour(x,y,z)
filled.contour(x,y,z,color.palette=rainbow)
z2 <- z
z2[5,5] <- Inf
filled.contour(x,y,z2,col=rainbow(200),nlevels=200)
```

Is it possible to stack 2-3 of these plots next to each other with only one z value color key? I can do this in GIMP but I was wondering if it is natively in R possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No I do not think this is possible in `filled.contour`.

Although extensions have been written for you already. [To be found here](http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/index.php/R/Contour_Plots), [here](http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/index.php/File:Filled.contour3.R) and [here](http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/sites/qerm/images/1/16/Filled.contour3.R) and a [legend code here](http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/sites/qerm/images/2/25/Filled.legend.R).
[If you are using the filled.contour3 function referred to on those sites, and using a more recent version, then you need to use the upgrade fix referred to in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813077/1299362)].
Using those codes I produced:

[image]

Comment: It's a shame that `filled.contour` has a personality of it's own. I find it very difficult to manipulate `filled.contour` plots. Thanks for pointing out the modified version and to Carey McGilliard and Bridget Ferris for putting their code out there http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/index.php/R/Contour_Plots

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved with `cowplot`.
The clue is the `cowplot::draw_plot` function which successfully represent the plot (`cowplot::draw_grob(~filled.contour(x,y,z))`).
Later the grob representations can be binded.
The possible problem is that each plot will have own legend.

```r
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
z <- matrix(outer(x,y,"+"),nrow=5)
z2 <- z
z2[5,5] <- Inf

cowplot::plot_grid(~filled.contour(x,y,z), ~filled.contour(x,y,z,color.palette=rainbow), ~filled.contour(x,y,z2,col=rainbow(200),nlevels=200))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>