# install R 2.15.3 on vanilla Debian 7.6

Tags: r, debian, cran

Debian 7 comes with R 2.15.1 in the repositories.

How can I upgrade to 2.15.3 **but not to 3.x.x** ?

Comment: Is installing from source an option you're willing to accept?

Comment: I would rather not compile

Comment: Is there are particular reason you don't want to fully upgrade to 3.x.x?

Comment: missing packages and code compatibility ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812528/filled-contour-in-r-3-0-x-throws-error ). Its a production machine so change is not good.