# Error when plotting RasterLayer in R 3.x.x

Tags: r, plot, r-raster

Since the release of R 3.x.x I have problems when plotting. Until now I was always able to go back to an older version to avoid this problem, but now I use packages which are not available for R 2.15.x.

Little example:

```
> r <- raster(matrix(1:25,5,5))
> r
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 5, 5, 25  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.2, 0.2  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 1, 25  (min, max)

> plot(r)
Error in par(no.readonly = TRUE) : there is no .Internal function 'par'
```

I'm using:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

I was already able to find some information about possible causes of this error ([R 3.0.0 is released! (what’s new, and how to upgrade)](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-3-0-0-is-released-whats-new-and-how-to-upgrade/)), but I was never able to find any hint how this problem can be solved.

Thank you for you help in advance!

Comment: Never had this problem in R version 3.1.2. It looks like `plot` is not recognizing the `Raster*` class.

Comment: It was the same with `raster::plot` ...

Comment: This means you have a corrupted installation of R, or at least of `raster` package.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16812528/489704) for similar.

Comment: Cannot reproduce -- R3.1.2, default OSX binary of `raster` installed; runs just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be solved by starting a new R-Studio project in a new directory!

First I thought I understand, because it is always possible, that some of my own functions in the environment could have be kind of conflicting, since they were created before 3.x.x.

But then I realized, that I still do not understand , because clearing the environment and history did not help in the first place.

Since I am a curious person, I'm still interested in ideas, which can explain that and I have absolutely no understanding for voting down my question without giving an explanation!