# Multiple Contour Plots in R

Tags: r

I have a problem when implementing the codes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758391/multiple-filled-contour-plots-in-one-graph-using-with-parmfrow-c). The error message was as follows.

> Error in .Internal(filledcontour(as.double(x), as.double(y), z, as.double(levels),  : 
>     there is no .Internal function 'filledcontour'

All I did was copy and paste the three files together, namely, filled.contour3.R, filled.legend.R and Example 4 panel contour plot with one legend.R from [here](http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/index.php/R/Contour_Plots).

```
  filled.contour3 <- function (x = seq(0, 1, length.out = nrow(z)),
            y = seq(0, 1, length.out = ncol(z)), z, xlim = range(x, finite = TRUE), 
            ylim = range(y, finite = TRUE), zlim = range(z, finite = TRUE), 
            levels = pretty(zlim, nlevels), nlevels = 20, color.palette = cm.colors, 
            col = color.palette(length(levels) - 1), plot.title, plot.axes, 
            key.title, key.axes, asp = NA, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", las = 1, 
            axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes,mar, ...) 
  {
    # modification by Ian Taylor of the filled.contour function
    # to remove the key and facilitate overplotting with contour()
    # further modified by Carey McGilliard and Bridget Ferris
    # to allow multiple plots on one page

    if (missing(z)) {
      if (!missing(x)) {
        if (is.list(x)) {
          z <- x$z
          y <- x$y
          x <- x$x
        }
        else {
          z <- x
          x <- seq.int(0, 1, length.out = nrow(z))
        }
      }
      else stop("no 'z' matrix specified")
    }
    else if (is.list(x)) {
      y <- x$y
      x <- x$x
    }
    if (any(diff(x) <= 0) || any(diff(y) <= 0)) 
      stop("increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected")
    # mar.orig <- (par.orig <- par(c("mar", "las", "mfrow")))$mar
    # on.exit(par(par.orig))
    # w <- (3 + mar.orig[2]) * par("csi") * 2.54
    # par(las = las)
    # mar <- mar.orig
    plot.new()
    # par(mar=mar)
    plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", xaxs = xaxs, yaxs = yaxs, asp = asp)
    if (!is.matrix(z) || nrow(z) <= 1 || ncol(z) <= 1) 
      stop("no proper 'z' matrix specified")
    if (!is.double(z)) 
      storage.mode(z) <- "double"
    .Internal(filledcontour(as.double(x), as.double(y), z, as.double(levels), 
                            col = col))
    if (missing(plot.axes)) {
      if (axes) {
        title(main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "")
        Axis(x, side = 1)
        Axis(y, side = 2)
      }
    }
    else plot.axes
    if (frame.plot) 
      box()
    if (missing(plot.title)) 
      title(...)
    else plot.title
    invisible()
  }

  filled.legend <- function (x = seq(0, 1, length.out = nrow(z)), y = seq(0, 1, 
                                                         length.out = ncol(z)), z, xlim 
    range(x, finite = TRUE), 
            ylim = range(y, finite = TRUE), zlim = range(z, finite = TRUE), 
            levels = pretty(zlim, nlevels), nlevels = 20, color.palette = cm.colors, 
            col = color.palette(length(levels) - 1), plot.title, plot.axes, 
            key.title, key.axes, asp = NA, xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", las = 1, 
            axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes, ...) 
   {
    # modification of filled.contour by Carey McGilliard and Bridget Ferris
    # designed to just plot the legend
    if (missing(z)) {
      if (!missing(x)) {
        if (is.list(x)) {
          z <- x$z
          y <- x$y
          x <- x$x
        }
        else {
          z <- x
          x <- seq.int(0, 1, length.out = nrow(z))
        }
      }
      else stop("no 'z' matrix specified")
    }
    else if (is.list(x)) {
      y <- x$y
      x <- x$x
    }
    if (any(diff(x) <= 0) || any(diff(y) <= 0)) 
      stop("increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected")
    #  mar.orig <- (par.orig <- par(c("mar", "las", "mfrow")))$mar
    #  on.exit(par(par.orig))
    #  w <- (3 + mar.orig[2L]) * par("csi") * 2.54
    #layout(matrix(c(2, 1), ncol = 2L), widths = c(1, lcm(w)))
    #  par(las = las)
    #  mar <- mar.orig
    #  mar[4L] <- mar[2L]
    #  mar[2L] <- 1
    #  par(mar = mar)
    # plot.new()
    plot.window(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = range(levels), xaxs = "i", 
                yaxs = "i")
    rect(0, levels[-length(levels)], 1, levels[-1L], col = col)
    if (missing(key.axes)) {
      if (axes) 
        axis(4)
    }
    else key.axes
    box()
  }
#
#    if (!missing(key.title)) 
#        key.title
#    mar <- mar.orig
#    mar[4L] <- 1
#    par(mar = mar)
#    plot.new()
#    plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", xaxs = xaxs, yaxs = yaxs, asp = asp)
#    if (!is.matrix(z) || nrow(z) <= 1L || ncol(z) <= 1L) 
#        stop("no proper 'z' matrix specified")
#    if (!is.double(z)) 
#        storage.mode(z) <- "double"
#    .Internal(filledcontour(as.double(x), as.double(y), z, as.double(levels), 
#        col = col))
#    if (missing(plot.axes)) {
#        if (axes) {
#            title(main = "", xlab = "", ylab = "")
#            Axis(x, side = 1)
#            Axis(y, side = 2)
#        }
#    }
#    else plot.axes
#    if (frame.plot) 
#        box()
#    if (missing(plot.title)) 
#        title(...)
#    else plot.title
#    invisible()
#}



  MakeLetter <- function(a, where="topleft", cex=2)
  legend(where, pt.cex=0, bty="n", title=a, cex=cex, legend=NA)

#------------------------------------------------------
#Generate some fake data
x = rep(c(10,11,12),length = 9)
y = rep(c(1,2,3),each = 3)
z = runif(n=9,min = 0,max = 1)


xcoords = unique(x)
ycoords = unique(y)
surface.matrix = matrix(z,nrow=length(xcoords),ncol=length(ycoords),byrow=T)
#------------------------------------------------------

#plot.new() is necessary if using the modified versions of filled.contour
plot.new()

#I am organizing where the plots appear on the page using the "plt" argument in "par()"
par(new = "TRUE",plt = c(0.1,0.4,0.60,0.95),las = 1,cex.axis = 1)

#Top left plot:
filled.contour3(xcoords,ycoords,surface.matrix,color=terrain.colors,xlab = "",ylab = "",xlim = c(min(xcoords),max(xcoords)),ylim = c(min(ycoords),max(ycoords)),zlim = c(min(surface.matrix),max(surface.matrix)))
#The xpd=NA allows for writing outside the plot limits, but still using the the x and y axes to place the text
par(xpd = NA)
text(x=11,y=1.5,"x",cex = 1.5,font = 2)
MakeLetter("(a)")

#Top right plot:
par(new = "TRUE",plt = c(0.5,0.8,0.60,0.95),las = 1,cex.axis = 1)
filled.contour3(xcoords,ycoords,surface.matrix,color=heat.colors,xlab = "",ylab = "",xlim = c(min(xcoords),max(xcoords)),ylim = c(min(ycoords),max(ycoords)),zlim = c(-1,1))
#Alternatively, you could set z axis limits to depend on the min and max values in surface.matrix.
#filled.contour3(xcoords,ycoords,surface.matrix,color=heat.colors,xlab = "",ylab = "",xlim = c(min(xcoords),max(xcoords)),ylim = c(min(ycoords),max(ycoords)),zlim = c(min(surface.matrix),max(surface.matrix)))
text(x=11,y=1.5,"x",cex = 1.5,font = 2)
MakeLetter("(b)")

#Bottom left plot:
par(new = "TRUE",plt = c(0.1,0.4,0.15,0.5),las = 1,cex.axis = 1)
filled.contour3(xcoords,ycoords,surface.matrix,col=gray(seq(1,.1,length=11)), nlevels=11,xlab = "",ylab = "",xlim = c(min(xcoords),max(xcoords)),ylim = c(min(ycoords),max(ycoords)),zlim = c(-1,1))
text(x=11,y=1.5,"x",cex = 1.5,font = 2,col = "white")
MakeLetter("(c)")

#Bottom right plot:
par(new = "TRUE",plt = c(0.5,0.8,0.15,0.5),las = 1,cex.axis = 1)
filled.contour3(xcoords,ycoords,surface.matrix,color = terrain.colors,xlab = "",ylab = "",xlim = c(min(xcoords),max(xcoords)),ylim = c(min(ycoords),max(ycoords)),zlim = c(-1,1))
text(x=11,y=1.5,"hello",cex = 1.5,font = 2)
MakeLetter("(d)")

#Add a legend:
par(new = "TRUE",plt = c(0.85,0.9,0.25,0.85),las = 1,cex.axis = 1)
filled.legend(xcoords,ycoords,surface.matrix,color = terrain.colors,xlab = "",ylab = "",xlim = c(min(xintercepts),max(xintercepts)),ylim = c(min(slopes),max(slopes)),zlim = c(-1,1))

#Add some figure labels
par(xpd=NA,cex = 1.3)
text(x = -16.7,y = 0,"slope",srt = 90,cex = 1.3)
text(x = -8,y = -1.62,expression(paste(italic(x),"-intercept",sep = "")),cex = 1.3)
```

Initially, I thought it was because **filledcontour** should be **filled.contour**. However, after this change almost the same error message popped up. Or maybe this is some version problem since the codes were written in 2010. Can anyone tell me why I had such problem and how to fix it, please?

Comment: It's best if you make your question complete. Put all the necessary code here rather than making us go track it down. Perhaps you made a mistake in how you put the code together. You should also include sample input data to make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MrFlick I could do that. However, it is very long since there are two very long functions there. I tried to attach a r file, but it seems that it is not possible.

Comment: @MrFlick I pasted the codes above. Two functions are filled.contour3 and filled.legend. Thereafter the example started. From linked question, you can see the graph supposed to get from these codes. However, I always get error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pasting the code is very helpful. It looks like there have been changes to the way filled.contour works since that code was first posted. Change the line

```
.Internal(filledcontour(as.double(x), as.double(y), z, as.double(levels), 
       col = col))
```

to

```
.filled.contour(as.double(x), as.double(y), z, as.double(levels), 
       col = col)
```

Doing that I got the plot

[image]