# Place points at different places on filled.contour3 plots

Tags: r

I am using the [filled.contour3](http://wiki.cbr.washington.edu/qerm/sites/qerm/images/1/16/Filled.contour3.R) function in the mannner described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14758707/1299362). My code is like this

```
  plot.new()
  par(mfrow = c(3,3))
  pop_x <- 3.0
  pop_y <- 6.0
  for (i in 1:9){
    b_x <- calc_b_x(i)
    b_y <- calc_b_y(i)
    x <- calc_x(i)
    y <- calc_y(i)
    z <- calc_z(i)
    filled.contour3(x, y, z)
    text(x = pop_x, y = pop_y , 'x', cex = 1.5, font = 2)
    text(x = b_x, y = b_y , 'a', cex = 1.5, font = 2)
  }
```

This successfully plots 9 graphs in 3 rows. It also puts one 'x' on each graph in the correct position. However the second text call ends up putting 9 'a's on each plot, each in right position. But I only on want one 'a' on each graph, in the correct position for that graph. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was not a problem with `filled.contour3`. The `b_x` and `b_y` were mistakenly vectors rather than scalars, so a single call to

```
text(x = b_x, y = b_y , 'a', cex = 1.5, font = 2)
```

produced many points.